# How to Play Music in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, audio-player, android-music-player

Okay, So I am Making an app called Fall Down 4 in Android Studio. Now, I need to know if there is any way I can play music once I run my app.

I know how to start a music once you click on a certain button but that's not what I want. What i want to know if if there is any way that When I run my app, It just starts playing the music.

For Example: Many of the Games have music playing at the back when you run and then u have option in settings to turn it off. One Game Would be Fall Down Delux where the Music Keeps playing until I press the Turn Off Button.

So Please let me know if there is any way that I could do what I have explained above.

Thank You.

Comment: You would have to start the music on one of the lifecycle methods for an activity or fragment. Like onResume().

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to put your .mp3 file in /res/raw for this to work! (Just create a new folder named "raw" in /res)

Write this in your OnCreate() in your MainActivity:

```
class song extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.yoursong);

    mediaPlayer.start();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();

}
```

}

Comment: It would make more sense to call mediaPlayer.release() during onStop(). Currently if the user leaves the app without destroying it, they would have to start the media player again in another function besides onCreate(). Also starting the media player should happen during onResume() so it starts when the user enters the app again.

Comment: Thank You So Much.. I Finally Got It. Works Perfectly. But I Don't Understand Why It would not play the Music when I Close the App and Then Start Again. Like Can you Tell Me What I have to Replace the onResume In Order for the music to Re Start whenever the user closes-opens the app. Please and Thank

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Daniels answer, I'd move the **mediaPlayer.start()** to **onResume()** in the Activity. That way, the song starts playing if you put your device on standby and turn it back on.

(I need 50 reputation to comment, so I'm sorry I couldn't do it like that ^^')

Comment: Thank You So Much.. I Finally Got It. Works Perfectly. But I Don't Understand Why It would not play the Music when I Close the App and Then Start Again. Like Can you Tell Me What I have to Replace the onResume In Order for the music to Re Start whenever the user closes-opens the app. Please and Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void playMusic(String url) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```